# How can I compact a Time Machine backup history in .backupbundle format?

Tags: macos, mac, backup, time-machine

I just got a more recent MacBook Pro than my current Late 2013 and in the transitory time in which I'll still have both but using only the newer one, I would like to keep the most recent part of the Time Machine history of the older one which went way back, occupying some 1TB of data.
I've already trimmed 2/3 of the oldest snapshots (of the original ~40) with the `tmutil delete` command but the overall occupied space diminished by just about 250GB. I suspect there'd be some (or much) space to be claimed possibly.

I've read about the `hdiutil` command which has a specific `compact` subcommand for the purpose but this seems to work only with .sparsebundle Time Machine backups format and I can't find any alternative to be used with the .backupbundle format.

What am I missing? Is there any free alternative command or utility to do the job?

P.S. The MacBook Pro in question runs on Catalina

Comment: tbh, I'd just put the old drive on a shelf & start a new one. Time Machine has always been fairly intransigent but since the shift to APFS has become a whole new level of *^*%*$*£*!.

Comment: Thanks @Tetsujin, but this is an easy option I can always have. Yet, if possible, I'd like to keep the last months of history, for the same reasons why I created it on the first place.

Comment: Even Apple have removed their instructions on how to move TM structures. They replaced that with 'put your drive on a shelf'.